# Optimization : How to improve if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, optimization

I have multiple images with a shape in it. And I would like to box this shape for later cropping those images. I want every image to have the same cropping box (the variation in coordinates between the shapes is not much).

I got this code working :

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np

def Region():

    path = glob.glob('label/*.tif')
    L = [640,640,0,0]
    for img_name in path:
        x = []
        y = []
        img = Image.open(img_name)
        pic = np.array(img)

        for index, lit in enumerate(pic):
            for indox, value in enumerate(lit):
                if value == 0:
                    y.append(index)
                    x.append(indox)

        if min(y) < L[0]:
            L[0]=min(y)
        if min(x) < L[1]:
            L[1]=min(x)
        if max(y) > L[2]:
            L[2]=max(y)
        if max(x) > L[3]:
            L[3]=max(x)

   print L
```

And it gives me this output [298, 258, 424, 386] which correspond well to what I want. 
But *in fine* I need to treat a lot of data and I am sure that there might be a better way to do that.

Since I am fairly new in programming I would like to know if there is a better way to do this task.

Any advices ?

Thank you very much,

Regards

EDIT : if statement L[3] ':'

Comment: Your last `if` statement is missing a `:` and the statement to execute when it's true.

Comment: Never mind my first comment, I didn't notice the difference between `index` and `indox`. You should use better variable names, like `x_index` and `y_index`.

Comment: Questions about improving coding style are more appropriate for [codereview.se]

Comment: @Barmar Indeed I didn't know this thank you. Yeah the if statement is correct on my code since it produces the output I want. Thank you. I mean is there a better way to put those if statement ?

Comment: You could determine the min and max during the `for` loops, rather than doing it as a separate step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the min and max during the loop, instead of after the loop.

```
    for index, lit in enumerate(pic):
        for indox, value in enumerate(lit):
            if value == 0:
                if index < L[0]:
                    L[0] = index
                if indox < L[1]:
                    L[1] = indox
                if index > L[2]:
                    L[2] = index
                if indox > L[3]:
                    L[3] = indox
```

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you very much ! Do you have other suggestions ?

Comment: There might be a way to take advantage of numpy or pandas to get the min and max indexes of zero elements directly from the array, rather than looping. But I don't know these modules well enough.